# DPLYR filter- why do i get error with object? Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : Evaluation error: object 'Email' not found

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, contains

I'm trying to filter email accounts that contain the domain "gmail"

here's how it goes:

```
library(dplyr)
GMAIL<- read.csv(file.choose())
GMAIL <- data.frame(lapply(GMAIL, as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
GMAIL2<-GMAIL
GMAIL2 %>%
filter(Email, contains("gmail"))
```

the error i get is:
Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : 
  Evaluation error: object 'Email' not found.

And my Data "GMAIL" only has one column named "Email"

I would also like to make a new dataset with the filtering result, how can I also accomplish this?

Thx in advance

Comment: Hi, I also tryed the following

>library(stringr)
>GMAIL2 %>%
  filter(str_detect(Email, "gmail"))

and the same error appears:
-Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : 
  Evaluation error: object 'Email' not found.

Comment: `contains` is not a verb used within `filter`. Perhaps you mean `GMAIL2 %>% filter(grepl("gmail", Email))`? I suggest some of the tutorials/docs at https://dplyr.tidyverse.org to fine-tune where you use column-finding verbs like `contains` and what can be used within `filter`.

Comment: please always post [reproducible questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) no one else on the internet has access to whatever file you pick after `file.choose()` >>> whatever.csv

Comment: hi nate, ok i'll do my best on the next query!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To filter and save the results to a new df:

```
filtered_gmail <- GMAIL2 %>%
  filter(grepl("gmail", Email))
```

Comment: Hi @feebarscevicius! Thanks for ur reply..
I tried your code but it still shows the same error:
Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : 
  Evaluation error: object 'Email' not found.

Comment: Indeed, I would not expect this error if only `contains` was the problem. Second arg of `filter` is `...` and if it tries to evaluate a character variable to logical I guess it gets `NA` and this might result different error. However, Marchelo, are you sure there is no typo? Your col name is "Email", not "email" or anything else?

Comment: can you post the output of `colnames(GMAIL2)`, please?

Comment: Hi! For sure:
> colnames(GMAIL2)
[1] "ï..Email"

I understand "ï.." has nothing to do....

Thx for your replies!

Comment: Hi! it seems the object despite it's called "Email" had to be referenced as "ï..Email"

>filtered_gmail <- GMAIL2 %>%
> filter(grepl("gmail", ï..Email))

Thanks to all for your replies!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `select` instead of `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
GMAIL<- read.csv(file.choose())
GMAIL <- data.frame(lapply(GMAIL, as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
GMAIL2<-GMAIL
GMAIL2 %>%
select(contains("gmail"))
```

Comment: Hi Nelson! I tried your solution but it made a very weird select and the final result was a very short list of emails but mixed by gmail, hotmail and more domains!
wird, huh?

Comment: Sorry I didn't have sample data so couldn't really test.